# FHIR STU3 ListResource.ListEntryComponent.getItemTarget() function not recognizing referenced Resource

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

I'm converting my code to FHIR STU3 and I'm trying to get the Organization Resource referenced by a List.entry[x].item.reference by calling getItemTarget() on the ListEntryComponent, but it always returns NULL although the resource is there (see `if (organizations.get(i).getItemTarget())` ). What can be wrong?

Here is part of the code I'm using:

```
if (entries0.get(e).getReference().equals("List/g1")) {

        //get the organizations list
        var organizations =  entries0.get(e).getResource().getEntry();

        for (var i = 0; i < organizations.size(); i++) {

            var orgReference = organizations.get(i).getItem();              

            if (orgReference.hasReference()) {

                //if the reference resolves, Organization.type must be present
                if (organizations.get(i).getItemTarget() && 
                    organizations.get(i).getItemTarget().getResourceType() == fhirPackageStruct.ResourceType.Organization) {

                    list1OrgTypeSystem = organizations.get(i).getItemTarget().getTypeFirstRep().getCodingFirstRep().getSystem().equals("http://spms.min-saude.pt/pds/codings/nn_organization_types");
                    throwIfTrue(!list1OrgTypeSystem,'Composition.section[0].entry['+e+'].entry['+i+'].item ' + orgReference.getReference(), "INVALID Organization.type.system. Expected: http://spms.min-saude.pt/pds/codings/nn_organization_types");
                }
                else {
                    throw 'srcTransf validateNNDocumentProfile: não foi encontrado o recurso referenciado por ' + orgReference.getReference() + ' da lista de instituições de seguimento da grávida.';
                }

                orgReference = orgReference.getReference().toLowerCase();
            }               

            if (orgReference.equals("organization/hospital")) {

                section0HospMotive = organizations.get(i).getItemTarget().getExtension().isEmpty();
                throwIfTrue(section0HospMotive,'Composition.section[0].entry['+e+'].entry['+i+'].item (Organization/Hospital)', "MISSING FOLLOWUP MOTIVE EXTENSION");
            }
        }   
}
```

Can you please help me? Thank you!!

Comment: Thanks for the tag @Lloyd :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getFOOTarget()` methods are a bit confusing, they aren't actually used and will probably be removed.

You need to replace `getItemTarget()` with `getItem().getResource()`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I forgot to mark it here as resolved (you already answered to me yesterday at Zulip Forum). Thank you very much for your time! :)